# Set different timer attribute for azure function

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I want to deploy my Azure Function App in different environments (Test, Acceptance, Production). It is a time triggered function, to be run in Production every night. I don't want this, however, when I'm testing and debugging it, i.e., when it is run in the Dev and Acc environments. 
Currently, my timer attribute is as follows:

```
public class TimedAzFunction
{   
   // CTOR 
   public TimedAzFunction()
   { 
   }

   // How to set the timer (using CRON notation):
   // "0 30 3 * * 1-5" for prod
   // Runs every 5 mins: "0 */5 * * * *" for dev and acc
   [FunctionName("TimedAzFunction")]
   public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)  
   {
      // Code for function here
      // ...
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, this means that  I have to change it manually when I want to publish it, which is error prone.

I tried doing something with local settings and evaluating the value, and then create a TimerTrigger object, but that didn't work.
How can I set up a timer based on the environment it is running in, for example using `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` and `my local.settings.json`?
Specifically, I want the Function to run every night at 3am, and in Dev and Acc envirnonments every 5 or 10 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a value in the "Application settings" of your function app on azure portal(in each environment of your function such as dev/prod).
[image]

In your function code, just edit the code like below:
[image]

When you deploy the function from local to azure, it will be triggered by the value of "myTimerCron" in your "Application settings".

Hope it helps~

If your function is running via multiple deployment slots, enable the "Deployment slot setting" option in "Add/Edit application setting" to ensure the timer settings don't get clobbered when switching slots.  See [the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#create-a-deployment-setting) for details.

Comment: That is a very simple solution! I'm gonna try it asap, thank you very much. The timer settings can also be included in the appsettings.json or local.settings.json for local debugging?

Comment: Yes, you can also set the `myTimerCron` in your local.settings.json when you test it in visual studio such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOcyP.png).